# Use webcam from laptop on desktop pc

Tags: networking, webcam, streaming, video-streaming, v4l

I want to use the webcam on my laptop as video device on my pc to use it for video conferencing etc.

So I not just want to stream the video. I actually want to "stream" the entire device over network.

So, two computers, one streams its webcam, the other picks it up as video device.

Both computes run normal Ubuntu 18.04 however I will soon upgrade to 20.04

Comment: So, two computers, one streams its webcam, the other picks it up as video device, is that it?

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) on the laptop and the desktop, and which release number for each? Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: If you specify your needs with a little more detail, you would receive more focused help.
In particular, if having the "remote" webcam exactly as if it were a local device is not possible.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Asuming both machines are connected in a network and the PC can reach the laptop's IP. Please follow these steps:

### On the laptop (with the webcam)

Install `v4l-utils` and `ffmpeg` by running:

```
sudo apt install v4l-utils ffmpeg
```

Install `matroska` media container like so:

```
sudo apt install libmatroska6v5
```

Run the following command to open a `netcat` listener for the camera stream:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f matroska - | nc -l 9999
```

### On the PC

Install `v4l-utils` and `ffmpeg` by running:

```
sudo apt install v4l-utils ffmpeg
```

Install `v4l2loopback` and load the virtual camera:

```
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils

sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback

sudo depmod -a

sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 card_label="MyLaptopCam:MyLaptopCam"
```

**Test it:**

1. Stream the real camera on the laptop to the virtual camera on the PC ( change `Laptop_IP` to the IP of the laptop ):

   ```
   nc Laptop_IP 9999 | ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video0
   ```
2. Launch and play the virtual camera:

   ```
   ffplay /dev/video0
   ```
3. Say **cheese** to your laptop's camera.

If you can see your face, then it's working.

### Microphone?

To send over the microphone output as well from the laptop to the PC, please follow these steps:

**On the laptop:**

```
arecord -f cd -c 1 | nc -l 7777
```

**On the pc:**

```
sudo modprobe snd-aloop

arecord -l | grep -i loopback
```

The output will be something like this:

```
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 0: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
card 1: Loopback [Loopback], device 1: Loopback PCM [Loopback PCM]
```

we will use **device 1** ( this is usually the virtual microphone ) on **card 1** like this `hw:1,1`

1. Then run this ( change `Laptop_IP` to the IP of the laptop ):

   ```
   nc Laptop_IP 7777 | aplay -f cd -D hw:1,1
   ```
2. Select the new microphone device in System Setting -> Sound -> Input.

Test the microphone and be advised there will be sound latency because no compression is used.

### Notice

- This has been tested and working flawlessly on two machines running **up to date equal versions of Ubuntu 19.10**.

If the test fails, then it is probably because you have other camera devices virtual or otherwise present in your PC's `/dev` directory.

To fix this, run `ls /dev/video*` and note how many are there. Then use the one with the greater number after it in the two commands in the test. This is done like so:

1. Run `sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback`
2. Then run `ls /dev/video*` and note the existing cameras like `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2 ... etc`
3. Then run:

   ```
   sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1 card_label="MyLaptopCam:MyLaptopCam"
   ```
4. Then run again `ls /dev/video*` a new camera `/dev/video3` will be added like so `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2 /dev/video3`
5. Use the new camera in the last two commands instead of `/dev/video0` like so:

   ```
   nc Laptop_IP 9999 | ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video3

   ffplay /dev/video3
   ```

### Troubleshooting

**To test if the stream is going through** if you are having issues with `v4l2loopback`, you can run on the PC:

```
nc Laptop_IP 9999 | mplayer -
```

or

```
nc Laptop_IP 9999 | vlc -
```

or

```
nc Laptop_IP 9999 | ffplay -
```

**To use it with Google Hangouts:**

Thanks to [@janjaromirhorak](https://askubuntu.com/users/285116/janjaromirhorak) as indicated in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227927/virtual-webcam-with-video4linux2-not-available-in-some-videochat-services#comment2066772_1227927) quoted below.

> There might be more ways to do this, but this was my method in Mozilla
> Firefox: Open Google Hangouts, start a videocall and allow both
> requests for microphone and internal webcam. Then click the cogwhell
> icon to open a settings dialog that allows you to choose which webcam
> you want to use. Select your virtual webcam, accept the permission
> request and click "done". Also this setting seems to persist to future
> videocalls - next time I found my virtual webcam already selected and
> working. :)

Comment: The streaming on the laptop seem to work. however i got "/dev/stdin: Invalid data found when processing input" error on the pc. so i tried to run it locally and it gave me this error: 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> rawvideo (native))
[v4l2 @ 0x561b1778b3c0] ioctl(VIDIOC_G_FMT): Invalid argument
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- 
Conversion failed!

Comment: @JohnDoe This means missing v4l2 format. Install it by  running  `sudo apt install v4l-utils ffmpeg` on both

Comment: no it is installed. has to be something else

Comment: @JohnDoe run `sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback` then run `ls /dev/video*` and note the existing cameras like `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2 ... etc` then run `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_capse=1` and run again `ls /dev/video*` a new camera will be added like so `/dev/video0  /dev/video1  /dev/video2 /dev/video3` use the new camera in the commands under test instead of `/dev/video0`

Comment: I already did that /dev/video2 is the new video device on my machine. So I run "ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -f matroska - | nc -l 9999" and "nc 127.0.0.1 9999 | ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -f v4l2 /dev/video2"

Comment: @JohnDoe Did you install `v4l2loopback` this way `sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils`?

Comment: Yes I did. So I guess we are stuck here. But I feel like we are very close. Maybe it will work once I upgrade to 20.04. If no one else will post an answer which works on my machine I will award you the bounty. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: @JohnDoe Try this from the PC instead `nc Laptop_IP 9999 | mplayer -` and if it works then it is most likely `v4l2loopback` is the cause. so reinstall it the right way or the package available for Ubuntu 18.0 is outdated, I tested it on Ubuntu 19.10 and it works flawlessly.

Comment: @JohnDoe Check the version with `apt policy v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms`. I tested it on version `0.12.2-1` of `v4l2loopback`

Comment: i have 0.10.0-1. and mplayer works. i am on ubuntu 18.04. So it should work on 20.04

Comment: @JohnDoe Answer updated to minimize latency

Comment: I know I didnt ask for it but could you do a bonus for the microphone if you know how to do that?

Comment: @JohnDoe No problem. Please check the updated answer. There will be sound latency because no compression is used.

Comment: I'm getting `pipe:: Invalid data found when processing inputKB sq=    0B f=0/0   
` when I run `nc Laptop_IP 9999 | ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video0`

Comment: @FitzWatson Yoy need to change `Laptop_IP` to the actual IP of the laptop which can be something like `192.168.1.116` for example.  Use the GUI of network manager or run `ip address` in the terminal to find out what the actual laptop's IP is and use that instead.

Comment: I'm streaming from user A in laptop to user B in the same laptop. So I replaced it with localhost. Is that ok?

Comment: https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/xephyr.html

Comment: I've followed this guide and am now trying to get webcam in the xephyr session

Comment: @FitzWatson Yes `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` should work, but open a new terminal for that command and leave the first terminal open to keep `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f matroska - | nc -l 9999` running . I have not looked at the link you provided though and do not know whether it is compatible or not.

Comment: I did this: 1) Opened new terminal and ran `ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -codec copy -f matroska - | nc -l 9999`. Webcam led on. 2) Opened new terminal and ran `nc 127.0.0.1 9999 | ffmpeg -i /dev/stdin -codec copy -f v4l2 /dev/video0`. 3) This gave `/dev/stdin: Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: @FitzWatson Test it with `nc 127.0.0.1 9999 | mplayer -` in the second terminal instead and make sure the command in the first terminal is running and if it works then you need to work with the format and see what is best for your solution. This test should work if you have followed the instructions in the answer correctly.

Comment: This is the output of the mplayer command. https://pastebin.com/4eq4KjQs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119889/discussion-between-fitz-watson-and-raffa).

Comment: This works awesome! But its abit lag, is there any way to compress or reduce the bitrate for example?

Comment: @JiewMeng You can try encoding into a different format (AKA compression) before sending the stream over `nc` but that will result in even more latency/lag as processing will take more time than just copying the codec so not advisable … Lowering bitrate however can reduce latency although it will reduce quality as well and might not work as expected with all cameras but you can try your luck with it if you wish … I remember trying all that when I wrote the above answer and the described way gave the least latency I could get back then … so IMHO that’s the best it could be :-)

Answer (score 4):

So you want to borrow the camera for another machine. May be late but this question seems to have solution.

The usual issue I see, most conference/chat apps does only support local camera devices (no network or local file streaming).

Your are missing only one piece:

### `v4l2loopback`

1. Create a V4L2 loopback device in Desktop(PC2)
2. In Laptop(PC1), use GStreamer(`gst-launch-1.0`), ffmpeg, vlc,  ... to stream video from cam device to network
3. In Desktop(PC2), use GStreamer(`gst-launch-1.0`), ffmpeg, vlc,  ... to receive and pipe video to theloopback device

Then set conference/chat apps in Desktop(PC2) use the V4L2 loopback device created in step (1) as camera.

**References:**

- [Redirect real webcam to a virtual webcam via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/1041544/26246)
- [Fake a webcam using a video loopback device?](https://askubuntu.com/a/158190/26246)
- [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)
- [gst-launch: network-streaming](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tools/gst-launch.html#network-streaming)

Comment: I like your OS agnostic approach with `gst-launch-1.0`: I cannot get the network-streaming commands running... do you know of a gstreamer device I can use on a windows webcam, in your example PC1, to stream instead of device `v4l2src`? Thanks @user.dz

Comment: @Leder `ksvideosrc` and you can also probe all available sources using `gst-device-monitor-1.0` , it gives verbose info including cmd parameters to use with `gst-launch-1.0` Reference: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/winks/index.html?gi-language=c

Comment: I do not get it: I think I open up a new question, this is my gstreamer error: `ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc:ksvideosrc0: Internal data stream error.`

Comment: @Leder I will check back your post  https://askubuntu.com/q/1227835/26246 when I give this setup an experiment shot

Comment: I'll be back!!!

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you mean to have a video device on one computer getting the input from a physical device on another.
Even if I do not have here the resources to test it, I guess it is possible. I remember some time ago doing something similar but not with video.
According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/321787/piping-video-device-over-ssh-or-tcptunnel) (also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/can-i-pipe-dev-video-over-ssh); both old posts), video can also be done.

**In summary**

Solutions and comments in those posts use `dd`, `ffmpeg` or netcat (`nc`) to dump/stream video, and `mplayer` or `vlc` to see the tunneled video, and even piping with `tee`.

If you first try any of the solutions available in posts above, and report feedback, it would be a good starting point for moving ahead.

Creating a local device, to access it exactly as if the webcam were connected locally, was not tested.
[This](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/watching-remote-webcam-over-piping-and-ssh-4175518483/#post5237445) (old post) suggests that using [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS) might do the trick.
YMMV, depending on what use you intend for the tunneled video.

**References**

1. [Piping video device over SSH or tcptunnel?](https://superuser.com/questions/321787/piping-video-device-over-ssh-or-tcptunnel)
2. [Can I pipe /dev/video over ssh](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2302/can-i-pipe-dev-video-over-ssh)
3. [Watching remote webcam over piping and SSH?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/watching-remote-webcam-over-piping-and-ssh-4175518483/#post5237445)
4. [SSHFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFS)

Answer (score 2):

## vlc

Using [vlc](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/index.html) is [one way](https://www.flexihub.com/share-webcam-over-network.html) to achieve this goal.

### Step 1 - setup

To install VLC on Debian, Ubuntu or Linux Mint:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vlc
```

To install VLC on Fedora, first enable RPM Fusion's free repository, then run:

```
$ sudo yum install vlc
```

To install VLC on CentOS or RHEL 6, first set up EPEL repository, and then use the following commands:

```
$ cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
$ sudo wget http://pkgrepo.linuxtech.net/el6/release/linuxtech.repo
$ sudo yum install vlc
```

### Step 2 - Verify Webcam in VLC

Make sure your webcam is detected by your Linux system and VLC.

You’ll need to know the webcam’s name for that. In the example below, the webcam is named `/dev/video0`.

```
$ ls /dev/video*
/dev/video0
```

Then you have to test video from your webcam. Here is the command you need to use, do not forget to replace "video0" with the name of your device.

```
$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0
```

If your webcam is successfully detected by VLC, you should be able to see your video stream.

### Step 3 - Configure Webcam Streaming on VLC

You have successfully detected your webcam in VLC, next is configuring webcam streaming.

In this example webcam is streamed over HTTP in WMV format. To configure VLC for webcam streaming, first launch VLC.

```
$ vlc
```

In VLC menu choose "Streaming".

On the screen select your webcam’s or audio device’s name, e.g., /dev/video0 for webcam, and hw:0,0 for audio. Tick "Show more options" checkbox and make a note of value strings in "MRL" and "Edit Options" fields. These strings will be used later in the tutorial. Click "Stream" button.

Verify the video source, e.g., v4l2:///dev/video, and click "Next" to continue.

Choose the destination, i.e., streaming method/target, of webcam streaming. In our example we choose HTTP from the drop down list, and click "Add".

Next, specify port number and path of a streaming service. For port number, type 8080; we assume the port number is not occupied, for path - "/stream.wmv". For transcoding choose "Video - WMV + WMA (ASF)" profile from the drop down list. Click "Next".

The next screen displays automatically generated stream output string. Make a note of it and click "Stream" button.

At this point, VLC should start streaming video from your webcam over HTTP. Streaming traffic is sent directly to localhost at TCP port number 8080, so you won’t be able to see anything in the VLC window.

To verify that VLC is running correctly at TCP port 8080, run the following command, and look for VLC.

```
$ sudo netstat -nap | grep 8080
```

### Step 4 - Watch Streaming Video from Webcam

Once a streaming server starts running, the webcam live feed is available at
`http://:8080/stream.wmv`

You can use VLC player or MPlayer to access the webcam feed as follows.

```
$ vlc http://:8080/stream.wmv
$ mplayer http://:8080/stream.wmv
```

If you are testing the feed from the same host, use loopback address 127.0.0.1 instead.

Comment: thanks for your response. however this is not what i wanted. I want to register this stream as video device so I can use it in firefox for video conferencing

Comment: @JohnDoe - Would you mind giving some more detail on how you mean to use this? A particular conferencing site? Please edit the OP, do not answer to comments.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use DroidCam. I do not have PC with laptop in the one place, so I've just tested it on Android phone and Ubuntu 19.10. There's Wifi Server option present you could try in your case.

Installation for Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-`uname -r`
sudo apt install v4l2loopback-dkms v4l2loopback-utils
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
wget https://www.dev47apps.com/files/600/droidcam-64bit.tar.bz2 -O droidcam.tar.bz2
tar xjvf droidcam.tar.bz2
cd droidcam-64bit/
sudo ./install
echo -e '[Desktop Entry]\n Version=1.0\n Name=DroidCam\n Exec=droidcam\n Icon=droidcam\n Type=Application\n Categories=Application' | sudo tee /usr/share/applications/droidcam.desktop
```

You could run it from terminal: `droidcam &`

[image]

Allowing it in firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 4747
```

[image]

For 20.04 this droidcam installation guide could not work. But I've found a different way described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235432/925971).

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be a little different, since all options are already given.

1. Install [TeamViewer](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-teamviewer-on-ubuntu-18-04/) and use it to connect to the laptop, the problem with this idea is that the laptop camera has to be pointed at you, even when you use the Desktop PC. This will work even if both computers are not on the same network. TeamViewer has a free(non-commercial) use and paid(commercial) use.
2. Use the remote connection
   You can use the [remote](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ubuntu-remote-desktop-builtin-vnc-compatible-dead-easy/) connection on your Dekstop computer with Ubuntu.