# gstreamer: windows webcam to ubuntu 18.04 streaming not possible

Tags: windows-10, webcam, gstreamer

I want to stream OS agnostic w/ gstreamer:

- PC1: Windows webcam
- PC2: Ubuntu box

I even cannot display my webcam on PC1 and get this error:

```
C:\Users\gerri\Desktop>gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc device-path="\\\\\?\\display\#int3470\#4\&5178020\&0\&uid13424\#\{6994ad05-93ef-11d0-a3cc-00a0c9223196\}\\\{c9eab5b4-784a-47a2-b783-24ba0fa1f9a9\}" ! image/jpeg, width=640, height=480 ! jpegdec ! videoscale ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency bitrate=500 speed-preset=superfast ! rtph264pay ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc:ksvideosrc0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstKsVideoSrc:ksvideosrc0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Thanks @user.dz for the setup in answer to this post, not the accepted answer:

[Use webcam from laptop on desktop pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225088/use-webcam-from-laptop-on-desktop-pc)

Comment: I am not sure if this post should be here or somewhere else like Superuser. Issue is on boarders between Windows/Ubuntu

Comment: Could you add output of: `gst-device-monitor-1.0.exe Video/Source` .Try these if they works for you: `gst-launch-1.0.exe ksvideosrc ! videoconvert ! autovideosink` and `gst-launch-1.0.exe ksvideosrc ! image/jpeg ! jpegdec ! autovideosink` . For streaming, I still struggling to find a working gst pipeline configuration with many old doc over the internet.

Comment: Yes, I am struggling, too : gstreamer documentation is not working as is!

Comment: Error `failed to start device monitor`

Comment: Which package did you install? I'm using stabe-msvc-64bit build here https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/windows/1.16.2/gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.16.2.msi within Windows7 , I could stream in same machine (Windows7) but not between Windows/Ubuntu. I need to verify Ubuntu build version may be there is a compatibility issue.

Comment: Same version number but `mingw`... On windows 10