# Droidcam unable to find dev/video0

Tags: droidcam

After recently installing a system update droidcam will no longer open and fails with the message:
Device not found (/dev/video[0-9]).
Did you install it?

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I don't really know what happened with previous droidcam source I was using to [install it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1226776/925971) on 19.10 a few weeks ago. But now I've found a [different source](https://github.com/aramg/droidcam/tree/master/linux) which works in my case on 20.04.

Steps I was using which could not be required if you've done them previously. It is better to run the next command:

```
$ sudo apt install v4l2loopback-utils v4l2loopback-dkms cmake nasm yasm pkg-config libgtk2.0-dev
$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback
$ v4l2-ctl --list-devices     # check if you have dummy video devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
/dev/video0
```

Build required dependencies:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg-turbo.git
cd libjpeg-turbo
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -G"Unix Makefiles" ../
make && sudo make install
```

Build droidcam from sources:

```
cd ~/Downloads
git clone https://github.com/aramg/droidcam.git
cd droidcam/linux
make
sudo ./install-dkms
```

Run it:

```
droidcam &
ffplay /dev/video1    # in your case it could be a different video device
```

Comment: It seems to be working now, but I can't use the ctrl+a autofocus. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You could ask additional question. Maybe someone could help

Comment: For `v4l2-ctl --list-devices `, it returns `Cannot open device /dev/video0, exiting.`. Is this normal?

Comment: @cytsunny try also `$ sudo modprobe v4l2loopback`

Comment: It retuns `modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'v4l2loopback': Operation not permitted` (I am sure I have added the `sudo`)

Comment: @cytsunny try `sudo su` and then `modprobe v4l2loopback` from root

Answer (score 4):

I disabled secure boot - see here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/DKMS

Then reinstalled Droidcam

```
gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r`

cd /tmp/
wget https://files.dev47apps.net/linux/droidcam_latest.zip
echo "957e5ff9e1762d0e912ee43a5f9083bb droidcam_latest.zip" | md5sum -c --
# OK?
unzip droidcam_latest.zip -d droidcam && cd droidcam
sudo ./install
```

Answer (score 0):

I think DroidCam looks for `v4l2loopback_dc` I get this error after updating the kernel. After this, the module is no longer in the folder of the current kernel.

When I get this error I usually resolve it by uninstalling and reinstalling DroidCam like this: https://www.dev47apps.com/droidcam/linuxx/

Reference: [Reddit- Suddenly, Droidcam ceases working](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/g95qld/comment/forpmar/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)