# Droicam working on Firefox but not on Chromium browser

Tags: firefox, chromium, webcam, droidcam

Following [this guide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1235432/379184), I have installed droidcam and connected my phone camera to my PC on  Ubuntu 22.02. I use https://webcamtests.com/ to test my camera and it is working on Firefox. However, using the same site, the camera is not detected on Chrome and Brave. It is also not detected on my Signal desktop client.

I suspect it is related to some sandboxing that both Chromium and Signal desktop are using. Is there a way to confirm? And any suggestion I can make the cam detectable on Chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading the module with the right parameters?

[v4l2loopback docs says:](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback)

*"If you encounter problems detecting your device with Chrome/WebRTC you can try 'exclusive_caps"*

```
modprobe v4l2loopback exclusive_caps=1
```