# How to use my laptop camera with SSH using my PC?

Tags: 20.04, ssh, remote-access

My PC and laptop are both connected to the same router, and I would like to turn the laptop camera and have it live feed on my PC.
My PC using Ubuntu 20.04 and Laptop Elementary OS6.

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.   *The laptop part of your question is off-topic (not Ubuntu or flavor); so the on-topic desktop PC just has to use viewing software compatible with whatever you decide to use on your off-topic laptop; the most important part is off-topic here, SE Unix & Linux allows both OSes*

Comment: Try `ssh -X <ip.address.of.laptop> cheese`. Replace `cheese` with the appropriate video capture software you have in the Elementary OS laptop. This approach only uses `ssh` and does not use any video software in the Ubuntu desktop PC. I am voting to close this question as off-topic. See [Connect two computers with SSH in a home LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107987/connect-two-computers-with-ssh-in-a-home-lan) for how to set up `ssh`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use webcam from laptop on desktop pc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225088/use-webcam-from-laptop-on-desktop-pc)